# Can't render the component received as a prop.children in my parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am unable to render the prop.children which has a component.

```
// code for Layout component which could not render the prop.children
render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <NavBar/>
        {props.children}
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
}

//code where I am trying to render the Layout component
  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Layout {...user}>
          <ListView user={user} />
        </Layout>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

//P.S. ListView is another component which accepts user props
```

I can't see anything for props.children when I inspect the DOM, though I can see Header, NavBar, Footer being rendered properly.

Comment: Can you share the code that passes the children to this component?

Comment: I have updated the code to include code that passes the children

Comment: do you see more when you use `<ListView user={user} />` directly outside of `<Layout`?

Comment: ahh, `props` should be `this.props`

Answer (score 2):

In a class you need to add `this` to access properties.

```
render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <NavBar/>
        {this.props.children}
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can see a TypeError in the console that `props` is undefined, then inside a class method, you need to use `this.props`.